# Unioning two LINQ queries

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

I just need to make full outer join with Linq, But When i union two quires i get this error:

[image]

Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'System.Linq.ParallelQuery

And here is my full Code:

```
using (GoodDataBaseEntities con = new GoodDataBaseEntities())
        {
            var LeftOuterJoin = from MyCustomer in con.Customer
                                join MyAddress in con.Address
                                     on MyCustomer.CustomerId equals MyAddress.CustomerID into gr
                                from g in gr.DefaultIfEmpty()

                                select new { MyCustomer.CustomerId, MyCustomer.Name, g.Address1 };

            var RightOuterJoin = from MyAddress in con.Address
                                 join MyCustomer in con.Customer
                                 on MyAddress.CustomerID equals MyCustomer.CustomerId into gr
                                 from g in gr.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                 select new { MyAddress.Address1, g.Name };

          var FullOuterJoin = LeftOuterJoin.Union(RightOuterJoin);
          IEnumerable myList = FullOuterJoin.ToList();

            GridView1.DataSource = myList;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
```

Comment: Union expects to IEnumerables to have the same type - your IEnumerables are not of the same type. Union can not be used that way.

Comment: you are unioning between two different object types with different properties, which won't work. I don't know how clever the compiler is if it will work if you add `MyAddress.CustomerID` to the second anonymous return type so the properties match

Comment: [LeftOutterJoins with LINQ](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/linq/UXPF181012-SQL-Joins-with-C) a simple web search would yield tons of results / examples

Answer (score 2):

The types of your two sequences are not the same, so you can't do a `Union`.

```
new { MyCustomer.CustomerId, MyCustomer.Name, g.Address1 };
new { MyAddress.Address1, g.Name };
```

Try making sure that the fields have the same names and types in the same order.

Answer (score 1):

Why not select it all as one thing? Depending on your setup (i.e., if you have foreign keys properly set up on your tables), you shouldn't need to do explicit joins:

```
 var fullJoin = from MyCustomer in con.Customer
                select new { 
                    MyCustomer.CustomerId, 
                    MyCustomer.Name, 
                    MyCustomer.Address.Address1,
                    MyCustomer.Address.Name
                };
```

Method syntax:

```
var fullJoin = con.Customers.Select(x => new 
{ 
    x.CustomerId, 
    x.Name, 
    x.Address.Address1,
    x.Address.Name
});
```

Comment: Thank DLeh, But when i type MyCustomer.Address i don't find Address1. Can you please help me

Comment: the name might be different, see what properties you have in `MyCustomer.Address` and pick the appropriate one. It's not rocket surgery

Answer (score 0):

`union` appends items from one collection to the end of another collection, so if each collection had 5 items, the new collection will have 10 items.

What you seem to want is to end up with 5 rows with more infomration is each.  That's not a job for `Union`.  You might be able to do it with `Zip()`, but you'll really be best with the single query as shown by DLeh.